# Does pte modifying go through the same page table as usual memory access do?

Tags: x86, operating-system, osdev

I know that usual memory access will go through page tables to do virtual address to physical address translation. But what about pte modifying? Say OS want to modify a process's page table entry, does it also go through the process's page table? In other word, is there an entry in the page table to point to itself?

Comment: To that one who has cast a close vote - how is that offtopic? There were numerous proposals for OSDev.SE on Area 51, none was accepted, because official statement of SE staff says "they are already covered on SO" - so again, how is that offtopic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on the CPU/MMU/hardware.

On x86 PTEs are normally modified when page translation is already enabled (don't confuse that with the initial set up of page tables, which can be done before enabling page translation) and thus the memory accesses must involve virtual to physical address translation.

You can, of course, turn off page translation. Or you can use DMA or other circuitry (or CPU) to change the memory contents from outside the CPU. But that's very unusual.

While I don't know a lot of different CPUs, it's fairly possible that some of them have special functionality to manipulate PTEs directly w/o address translation when accessing them.

On x86 it's also common to set up the page directory (the top-most page table) in such a way that one of its entries points back to the page directory. This lets you access all the PDEs and PTEs in a subrange of virtual addresses.

Comment: I'll focus on x86 right now. The thing I want to know is when OS modify one process' pte, will it go through the process' page table? I got answer from #osdev, they said instead of going through the process' page table, OS will map the process' page table somewhere in kernel space, and the modifying operation will go through the OS' page table. That's said, usual memory access and pte modifying will go through two different page tables. Is that correct?

Comment: That extra mapping isn't necessary. If it's the current process (meaning that CR3 points to all of its page tables), you can use the trick I outlined at the end of the answer. Whichever way you do it, if page translation remains enabled, it will affect all memory accesses.

Comment: You mean if OS want to modifying a running process' pte, it just use what CR3 point to (i.e., the process' page table) and does the modifying, no extra page table here? Since you said "If it's the current process ...", I guess when OS want to modify a not-running (i.e. switched out) process' pte, the OS still need to map the process's page table in kernel space as I said above?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "no extra page table here", but if the kernel is in the context of a process different from the one whose PTEs it wants to modify, then, yes, either it will have to create a temporary mapping to modify those PTEs or it will need to temporarily switch to that process (to its address space, IOW, load its CR3).

Comment: "no extra page table here" means there is only process' page table has been used. :)

Comment: Page tables contain a huge amount of information. For that reason, all CPUs that I've ever come across store the information of the page-tables in main-memory, and have machine registers that point to the PTEs (e.g. x86/x64 has CR3). Hence, almost all virtual mappings are mapped into themselves, and so changing a PTE mapping is just writing a value into memory.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. It's common to have one PTE point to the physical address of the page directory itself to make it accessible from virtual address space.